# Const Char to Byte Array in C++

Tags: c++, byte

I am converting a string to a constant char in preparation for sending it over a socket connection as so:

```
std::ostringstream oss1;
std::ostringstream oss2;

int code = 52;

oss1 << "4" << "1" << "0" << "0" << "0" << "0" << 224 + code / 16 << code % 16;

std::string var1 = oss1.str();

cout << var1.c_str() << '\n';

int msg_len3 = strlen(var1.c_str());

comm_send1 = send(sock, var1.c_str(), msg_len3, 0);
```

However, I need the output to be in bytes as so:

Convert constant char from:

```
4100002274
```

To this:

```
b'\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe3\x01'
```

In Python 3, which I am translating from I would simply use:

```
bytevar = bytes(stringvar)
```

...however I am struggling to find an equivalent in C++ which I am new to. Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: How would you know how to translate the *three* character `'2'`, `'2'` and `'7'` into the *single byte* value `227`? What would make those three characters different from e.g. `'4'` and `'1'` to form `41`? The string you have is a string of *characters* not a string of *bytes*. There's no natural boundary except the single characters encoded values.

Comment: Perhaps the solution is not to use strings to begin with, and instead go with e.g. [`std::vector<uint8_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) from the very start?

Comment: Is what you want to do ? convert from integer 4100002274 to array of bytes '4','1','4','1','0','0','0','0','2','2','7','4'

Comment: AFAIK, that Python wouldn't work either.

Comment: to clear things up, what I am trying to replicate is lines 435-446 of this Python project on GitHub, which definitely does work as I have tested it. I need to rewrite into C++ to get an executable as a plug in to something else. It was my understanding that the bytes function is producing something akin to a hex type output, but i could be completely wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/davidgroves/SkyPlusController/blob/master/skyremote.py

Comment: the conversion process seems to be going ok, until I hit this last bit

Answer (score 0):

That Python code you link to is doing something *very* different from your attempted C++ code. To begin with, it uses a *list* as argument to the `bytes` function, not a string.

The closest corresponding C++ structure is indeed a [`std::vector<uint8_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), like

```
std::vector<uint8_t> data1 = { 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, static_cast<uint8_t>(224 + code / 16), static_cast<uint8_t>(code % 16) };
```

You can send this data over a socket (or other byte-wise communicatrion channel) by passing a pointer to the first element, usually obtained by the [`data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) function:

```
send(sock, data1.data(), data1.size(), 0);
```

Comment: when i tried that i got a build error of namespace "std" has no member "vector". do i need to amend anything else?

Comment: nm, fixed that by adding the #include <vector>; header, however i now have more errors around converting code, which is an int into an unsigned char in the vector step...

Comment: @gdogg371 Easily solved with a [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast). Like for example `static_cast<uint8_t>(code % 16)`

Comment: so i now have this std::vector<uint8_t> data1 = { 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 224 + static_cast<uint8_t>(code / 16), static_cast<uint8_t>(code % 16) }; which is throwing the same error as before. have i misunderstood?

Comment: @gdogg371 Order and placement is important: `224 + static_cast<uint8_t>(code / 16)` first converts `code / 16` to the correct type, but then you have the addition which converts the whole expression back to `int` again.